# Proof-of-concept: distcc in Fink or MacPorts on Mac

Tags: linux, macos, macports, homebrew, fink

I've never been able to get distcc to work successfully in Fink or MacPorts on my Macs, despite much tweaking and hacking.

I have used distcc successfully on various Linux platforms, as well as on OS X proper.

Has anyone been able to get distcc to distribute compiling among several Macs from within Fink or MacPorts? How about HomeBrew? I'm mainly interested in proof-of-concept: Can it be done?

Comment: Can you define "not working successfully"?  What sort of problems have you been having?

Comment: @larsks distcc is set up on all machines. The compile occurs on the server machine without a hitch, but distccmon and network traffic shows that work isn't being distributed: Work is being done by server, but not clients. distccmon shows all the machines, but the only activity is on the server. All config files (server and client) have been verified as correct. SSH working on client/server pairs. Maintainers on Fink/MacPorts cannot verify that anyone is using the package successfully. My query is to "anyone out there" who may have got distcc to work on Fink, MacPorts or Homebrew.